# how to create two different 404 page for my two module

Tags: error, 404-page, 404, multi-vendor, vendor

i need two different 404 page for customer and vender.

i need different page for customer and different page for vender.

how can i do different page for customer and vender

Comment: I think you need add new router and that will identify that if page is 404 and that will coming for which page then redirect to ur custom page

Comment: No need for a custom router. Within the 404 simply identify customer or vendor and show different template. So the question becomes, how do you identify if it is a customer or vendor? Customer group? Another customer attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you use the event `controller_action_layout_load_before`. By setting up your events to listen to this you should be able to use the `action` and `layout` that are attached to this event.

```
<events>
    <controller_action_layout_load_before>
        <observers>
            <layout_test>
                <class>layout_test/observer</class>
                <method>changeLayoutEvent</method>
            </layout_test>
        </observers>
    </controller_action_layout_load_before>
</events>
```

Then you can check the action type in your observer to make sure you are working with the 404 page and then add a handle based on customer type. For you something like the following should be a good start:

```
$action = $observer->getEvent()->getAction();
if ($action instanceof Mage_Cms_IndexController && $action->getRequest()->getRequestedActionName() == 'noRoute') {
    if (// Add check for customer or vendor here) {
    $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate()
        ->addHandle('new_layout_handles');
    }
}
```

Then you simply need to add a layout update for the appropriate handle and change the template/design as desired.

```
Varien_Event Object
(
[_observers:protected] => Varien_Event_Observer_Collection Object
    (
        [_observers:protected] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[_data:protected] => Array
    (
        [action] => Mage_Cms_IndexController Object
            (
                [_currentArea:protected] => frontend
                [_sessionNamespace:protected] => frontend
                [_request:protected] => Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http Object
                    (
                        [_originalPathInfo:protected] => /sales/order/hdsa/
                        [_storeCode:protected] => 
                        [_requestString:protected] => /sales/order/hdsa/
                        [_rewritedPathInfo:protected] => 
                        [_requestedRouteName:protected] => 
                        [_routingInfo:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [_route:protected] => cms
                        [_directFrontNames:protected] => 
                        [_controllerModule:protected] => Mage_Cms
                        [_isStraight:protected] => 
                        [_beforeForwardInfo:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [_paramSources:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => _GET
                                [1] => _POST
                            )

                        [_requestUri:protected] => /amazoneclone/Web/index.php/sales/order/hdsa/
                        [_baseUrl:protected] => /amazoneclone/Web/index.php
                        [_basePath:protected] => /amazoneclone/Web
                        [_pathInfo:protected] => /sales/order/hdsa/
                        [_params:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [_rawBody:protected] => 
                        [_aliases:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [_dispatched:protected] => 1
                        [_module:protected] => cms
                        [_moduleKey:protected] => module
                        [_controller:protected] => index
                        [_controllerKey:protected] => controller
                        [_action:protected] => noRoute
                        [_actionKey:protected] => action
                    )

                [_response:protected] => Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http Object
                    (
                        [_body:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [_exceptions:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [_headers:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => Content-Type
                                        [value] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
                                        [replace] => 
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => X-Frame-Options
                                        [value] => SAMEORIGIN
                                        [replace] => 1
                                    )

                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => P3p
                                        [value] => CP="CAO PSA OUR"
                                        [replace] => 1
                                    )

                                [3] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => Http/1.1
                                        [value] => 404 Not Found
                                        [replace] => 
                                    )

                                [4] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => Status
                                        [value] => 404 File not found
                                        [replace] => 
                                    )

                            )

                        [_headersRaw:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [_httpResponseCode:protected] => 200
                        [_isRedirect:protected] => 
                        [_renderExceptions:protected] => 
                        [headersSentThrowsException] => 1
                    )

                [_realModuleName:protected] => 
                [_flags:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [_cookieCheckActions:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [_isLayoutLoaded:protected] => 
                [_titles:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [_removeDefaultTitle:protected] => 
            )

        [layout] => Mage_Core_Model_Layout Object
            (
                [_update:protected] => EM_Themeframework_Model_Layout_Update Object
                    (
                        [_elementClass:protected] => 
                        [_packageLayout:protected] => 
                        [_cacheId:protected] => 
                        [_cachePrefix:protected] => 
                        [_updates:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [_handles:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [default] => 1
                                [cms_page] => 1
                                [STORE_default] => 1
                                [THEME_frontend_default_em0117] => 1
                                [cms_index_noroute] => 1
                                [page_two_columns_right] => 1
                            )

                        [_subst:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [from] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => {{baseUrl}}
                                        [1] => {{baseSecureUrl}}
                                    )

                                [to] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] =>     http://192.168.10.223/amazoneclone/Web/index.php/
                                        [1] => http://192.168.10.223/amazoneclone/Web/index.php/
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [_blocks:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [_output:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [_area:protected] => frontend
                [_helpers:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [_directOutput:protected] => 
                [_xml:protected] => Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element     Object
                    (
                    )

                [_cacheId:protected] => 
                [_cacheTags:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [_cacheLifetime:protected] => 
                [_cacheChecksum:protected] => 
                [_cacheSaved:protected] => 
                [_cache:protected] => 
                [_elementClass:protected] =>     Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element
                [_xpathExtends:protected] => //*[@extends]
            )

        [name] => controller_action_layout_load_before
    )

[_hasDataChanges:protected] => 
[_origData:protected] => 
[_idFieldName:protected] => 
[_isDeleted:protected] => 
[_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
    (
    )

)
```

Comment: Thanks David 

i will try it and let u know